# Service like testflight for iOS + Android + BlackBerry

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, testflight, over-the-air

I have an application built with [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap), and I want to send it to my clients with an elegant interface and get feedback. I have used testflight before for iOS, but it is not available for Android or BlackBerry.

I installed HockeyKit on my server. The alpha version of HockeyKit supports Android but there are a lot of files to upload and organize.

Is there any solution that can handle all three platforms - iOS, Android and BlackBerry?

Comment: Thanks for quoting PhoneGap! Does it actually work? Could you (and how would you implement a service that uses Bluetooth, the microphone and the accelerometer using PhoneGap?

Comment: I doesn't  use that functionalitys, sorry i cant help you for this but you refer to documentation at : http://docs.phonegap.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AppBlade](http://appblade.com) supports all three of the platforms you are looking for. To be honest I have only used them for Android, but it worked pretty well for that. I also got some great support from their engineers when I had questions and they also seemed to be fairly responsive to feature requests.

Comment: Thank you, i test it in an ios test application and it look better then testFlightapp ( i don't test the sdk of both ). It's not free :( but it my only choice for now.

Comment: Rumor has it they may have some pricing changes soon to be more competitive in the freemium space.

Answer (score 6):

[Knappsack](http://knappsack.com) sounds like it might fit the bill.  It's a mobile application management platform that allows over the air installation of your apps and fine grained control of the users that have access to said apps.  It's open source, so you can install it on your own server, but there is also a free tier that may suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Can try [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/), but it does not work with Blackberry. It is the best analog testflight.

Comment: too expensive costing 300$ per year for most basic plan.

Answer (score 0):

It's early 2015 now and the solutions listed above either don't exist any more, or aren't free if you have more than a few apps/testers.

The best TestFlightApp.com alternative that I have found is Crashlytics. They support iOS and Android (no Blackberry).

Here's some info on the service: http://www.crashlytics.com/blog/launching-beta-by-crashlytics/

And here you can sign up: http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/

My customers prefer it to TestFlight, and for me as a developer it's also easier because they have an OS X app through which I can upload the archives and invite new testers (TestFlight's desktop app was broken for me).

Another really nice feature that Crashlytics offers is that (if you enable this feature), the OS X app will automatically upload the symbol files. When the app crashes for your testers, you'll get an email (when it's a new issue) and you can view statistics and stack traces of the crashes that occurred.

Comment: this service is saying we are high in demand so will reach u soon. :(